# drawImage for cropping does not work

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, crop, drawimage

Its been now two days that I'm struggling with drawImage javascript function without success.

I'm simply trying to crop part of a picture to create a new, smaller one.  I'm using a selection rectangle to select the part of the picture to copy, but there is always an offsett in the region taken and also a size error. I went all around to read about this function, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.  It probably the tree that hides the forest...

Here's a link to a test page [draw tester](http://axsyst.com/webdemo/draw/test_draw.php)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some proper way of examining the script your using?

Comment: You have 2 issues here,  Firstly you have resized you image to 500px, but the native image size is 300px.. You will need to take that into account.  Also you rectangle select is not relative to the image,.. eg. Place the rectangle top left, it should say 0,0.. But it's more like 30,70..

Comment: Sorry Chris. I've tried but I did not find the way to add my external ressources

Comment: Thanks Keith, you lead me into the right direction! I have updated my test page (follow the link provided) you better update cache since I also have changed the css and it may not load properly the first time

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problems was coming from the fact that drawImage is only working with image natural dimensions. If you stretch the image for any reason, you must then calculate the ratio between stretched and natural dimensions.

You also have to make sure that the selection rectangle is relative to the image and not the document or other parent element.

I have updated the link to a demonstration page of these facts [here](http://axsyst.com/webdemo/draw/test_draw.php)

Thanks to the good advices from Keith